# sorl thumbnail high cpu usage after "clear"

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

Well I was getting "Thumbnail tag failed" (but everything was working fine)

So according to :
[Thumbnail tag failed: (sorl-thumbnail 11.12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940281/thumbnail-tag-failed-sorl-thumbnail-11-12)

I ran manage.py clear and then ./manage.py cleanup.

Ever since then, cpu has been choking and maxed out from the exact moment I ran those commands.

I profiled it and it was sorl thumbnail causing it.

How can I reverse this? I think it was the clear method

Am desperate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in sorl thumbnail.

I had to update the pip package and it solved it.